# htaccess / mod_rewrite stopped working -- ignoring rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website that I wrote and maintain for a client. I am currently hosting it on 1&1. The website was working perfectly up until 3-4 weeks ago. No changes were made to it anywhere in that time frame, the client just noticed that the redirects were no longer working.

The site is set up so that all urls are redirected to a view.php file, which then loads the correct page into the website template using a php include statement.

There are three main test cases:

1. `http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/industrial-safety`
   should redirect to: `/view.php?fs=workplace&p=industrial-safety`
2. `http://www.hazardcontrol.com/library/topical-index`
   should redirect to: `/view.php?f=library&p=topical-index`
3. `http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/pdfs/workplace-safety-programming.pdf` should NOT redirect

When it first broke (loaded the view.php page, but can't find the correct content page to include), I used a php echo statement in the view.php file to find out what the GET variables were that were being passed. Consistently they turned out to be f=reset: and p=view, no matter what url was tried.

I tried editing the htaccess file to update it and make sure everything was clean, simple, and correct. Now, case 1 is working fine. Case 2 was working 5 minutes ago, but isn't now - it tries to redirect to the view page. Case 3 is going straight to the '/library/topical-index.php' page that actually holds the content instead of redirecting to the view.php page so that it loads inside the template. Both htaccess files are below.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

**Original htaccess file**

(which WAS working. I did try calling 1&1, but they assured me they hadn't done anything except update Apache a little over a month ago, but that was before my site broke so it MUST be my script).

NOTE: last 8 rewriterules are the relevant ones.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Exceptions to rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(phaseout)($|/) - [L]

#Control user navigation quirks (like just deleting parts of the link)
redirect 301 /index.htm http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /default.htm http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /default.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.hazardcontrol\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.hazardcontrol.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.hazardcontrol.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Ensure the website is always addressed as www.hazardcontrol.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hazardcontrol\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hazardcontrol.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /sitemanagement/404
ErrorDocument 403 /sitemanagement/403

redirect 301 /coreprinciples.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/principles/core-principles
redirect 301 /emailus.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/about/contact-us
redirect 301 /agricultural.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/agricultural-safety
redirect 301 /BuildingCode.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /construction.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/construction-safety
redirect 301 /consultants.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/about/about
redirect 301 /copyright.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/copyright/copyright
redirect 301 /craneandhoist.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/construction-safety
redirect 301 /fallprevention.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/falls/design-of-fall-protection-systems
redirect 301 /gnelson.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/about/bio
redirect 301 /humanfactors.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/humanfactors/human-factors-and-ergonomics
redirect 301 /index.htm http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /jenglish.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/about/about
redirect 301 /jobs.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /lifting.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/landmark-manual-lifting-standards
redirect 301 /links.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /machineguarding.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/machineguarding/history-of-machine-guarding
redirect 301 /marine.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/marine-offshore-safety
redirect 301 /missing.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /ml-design.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/NIOSH-guidelines-and-revised-formula
redirect 301 /ml-historical http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/evolution-of-manual-lifting-standards
redirect 301 /ml-niosh81.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/NIOSH-guidelines-and-revised-formula
redirect 301 /ml-niosh93.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/NIOSH-guidelines-and-revised-formula
redirect 301 /ml-training.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/main_page.php?folder=fs_workplace_safety&page=workplace_safety_training
redirect 301 /oilfield.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/construction_safety
redirect 301 /premises.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/five-types-of-same-level-falls
redirect 301 /product.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/product/basic-elements-of-product-safety-programming
redirect 301 /rampfalls.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/ramp-design-analysis
redirect 301 /slipandfall.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/falls/design-of-fall-protection-systems
redirect 301 /sliptrip.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/five-types-of-same-level-falls
redirect 301 /stairramp.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/design-of-fall-protection-systems
redirect 301 /stairwayfalls.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/stairway-design-analysis
redirect 301 /trial.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /tripandfall.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/five-types-of-same-level-falls
redirect 301 /vehiclefalls.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/falls/access-to-vehicles
redirect 301 /workplace.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/industrial-safety

#Rewrite dynamic URIs as static/flat URIs for user ease and search engine happiness
RewriteRule ^factsheets/([^/\.]+)/([^/.]+)$ view.php?fs=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^factsheets/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+).php$ view.php?fs=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^factsheets/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+).htm$ view.php?fs=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^factsheets/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+).html$ view.php?fs=$1&p=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ view.php?f=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+).php$ view.php?f=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+).htm$ view.php?f=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+).html$ view.php?f=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

**New htaccess file**

NOTE: Last 3 rewriterules are the relevant ones.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Exceptions to rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(phaseout)($|/) - [L]

#Control user navigation quirks (like just deleting parts of the link)
redirect 301 /index.htm http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /default.htm http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /default.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com

# -> Prevent users from accessing another domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.hazardcontrol\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.hazardcontrol.com/$1 [R=301,N]

# -> Prevent users from trying to access the 'index page' of a folder or section
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.hazardcontrol.com/$1 [R=301,N]

# -> Ensure the website is always addressed as www.hazardcontrol.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hazardcontrol\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hazardcontrol.com/$1 [R=301,N]

#Custom error docs
ErrorDocument 404 /sitemanagement/404
ErrorDocument 403 /sitemanagement/403

#Maintain legacy search engine page ranks by redirecting them to our new pages
redirect 301 /coreprinciples.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/principles/core-principles
redirect 301 /emailus.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/about/contact-us
redirect 301 /agricultural.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/agricultural-safety
redirect 301 /BuildingCode.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /construction.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/construction-safety
redirect 301 /consultants.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/about/about
redirect 301 /copyright.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/copyright/copyright
redirect 301 /craneandhoist.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/construction-safety
redirect 301 /fallprevention.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/falls/design-of-fall-protection-systems
redirect 301 /gnelson.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/about/bio
redirect 301 /humanfactors.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/humanfactors/human-factors-and-ergonomics
redirect 301 /index.htm http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /jenglish.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/about/about
redirect 301 /jobs.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /lifting.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/landmark-manual-lifting-standards
redirect 301 /links.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /machineguarding.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/machineguarding/history-of-machine-guarding
redirect 301 /marine.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/marine-offshore-safety
redirect 301 /missing.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /ml-design.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/NIOSH-guidelines-and-revised-formula
redirect 301 /ml-historical http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/evolution-of-manual-lifting-standards
redirect 301 /ml-niosh81.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/NIOSH-guidelines-and-revised-formula
redirect 301 /ml-niosh93.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/ml-mh/NIOSH-guidelines-and-revised-formula
redirect 301 /ml-training.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/main_page.php?folder=fs_workplace_safety&page=workplace_safety_training
redirect 301 /oilfield.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/construction_safety
redirect 301 /premises.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/five-types-of-same-level-falls
redirect 301 /product.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/product/basic-elements-of-product-safety-programming
redirect 301 /rampfalls.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/ramp-design-analysis
redirect 301 /slipandfall.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/falls/design-of-fall-protection-systems
redirect 301 /sliptrip.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/five-types-of-same-level-falls
redirect 301 /stairramp.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/design-of-fall-protection-systems
redirect 301 /stairwayfalls.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/stairway-design-analysis
redirect 301 /trial.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com
redirect 301 /tripandfall.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/premises/five-types-of-same-level-falls
redirect 301 /vehiclefalls.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/falls/access-to-vehicles
redirect 301 /workplace.html http://www.hazardcontrol.com/factsheets/workplace/industrial-safety

#Rewrite dynamic URIs as static/flat URIs for user ease and search engine happiness
RewriteRule ^(\.pdf)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^factsheets/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)(.*)$ view.php?fs=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)(.*)$ view.php?f=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all three cases working, I changed

```
RewriteRule ^(\.pdf)$ - [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.pdf)$ $1 [L]
```

and the PDF did not redirect. This worked because the regular expression `^(.*\.pdf)$` matched `factsheets/pdfs/workplace-safety-programming.pdf`.

To troubleshoot I used http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.

Comment: Thanks creemama.  I hadn't thought to try that for the pdfs.  The problem with case 2 is, even though it's working on the madewithlove, it's NOT working on 1&1. It's possible it's a 1&1 quirk, but was hoping it was just an error in my code somewhere that just happened to show up when they did some random update.

Comment: @bmen I don't see the rule that loads topical-index.php when tropical-index is requested. Have you checked if there are any odd rewrite rules in httpd.conf, or is there another .htaccess file in a parent directory?

Comment: It's the second to last one ... RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)(.*)$ view.php?f=$1&p=$2 [L].  I haven't uploaded but one htaccess file, and it's in the root directory for that domain.  Unfortunately, 1&1 doesn't trust me with access to the httpd.conf file =P